# Active Directory Username Formats

Tags: active-directory, user-management, user-accounts

I'm working on an open source project that will manage active directory users.  I am looking for feedback from Windows/Active Directory Admins on the formats of usernames they prefer or their organization uses.  I want to make sure the software allows admins to use the most popular formats when new users are created.  Here is the list I have so far:

```
 1. <firstname><lastname>
 2. <lastname><firstname>
 3. <lastname><firstinitial>
 4. <lastname><firstinitial><middleinitial>
 5. <firstinitial><lastname>
 6. <firstinitial><middleinitial><lastname>
 7. <firstname><lastinitial>
```

In addition how do you handle multiple identical names? So if two John Smith's exist do you append a numeric number, or interject a middle initial or name to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by manage?  I really don't understand what you are asking here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yea, its pretty simple, maybe its not clear.  When you create new users in active directory today what is the username format you use and why?  If the software I have allows you to create new users automatically through simple name input fields obviously you would want it to follow your naming convention.

Comment: In most of the environments I've managed, usernames were purposefully *not* related to the user's name to avoid issues with duplicate names, name changes, and all of the other headache involved with name based IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went a different direction with this question.  We ended up building dynamic elements that allow for any combination of the user's name to be used as a username.  However the formats above do appear to be the most used.

Brent